# Installing Metasploit Framework on OS X Yosemite, metasploit-framework -v '4.10.1.pre.dev' not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-yosemite, metasploit

I am trying to install Metasploit Framework on OS X Yosemite and whilst running `bundle install` the installer gets stuck on trying to install metasploit-framework -v '4.10.1.pre.dev'.

When I run `gem install metasploit-framework -v '4.10.1.pre.dev'` on it's own I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'metasploit-framework' (= 4.10.1.pre.dev) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: test_framework, metasploit-yard, metasploit-runner, metasploit-erd,         
metasploit-concern
```

Has anyone successfully installed msf on Yosemite that could help me out?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Gem needs more access, so if you are using RVM then Try this:

```
rvmsudo bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by going to the [github page](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework) for the framework and cloning it into my /opt directory. After I just ran `msfupdate` everything installed as normal!