# gem install metasploit-framework-db -v '4.11.0.pre.dev

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-mavericks, metasploit

Trying to install Metasploit Framework on OS X Maverick following [this guide](http://www.labrat.com/2014/02/how-to-install-metasploit-on-mavericks.html). I got to step 15, but while running bundle install the installer gets stuck on trying to install metasploit-framework -v '4.10.1.pre.dev' with the following error:

`Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - metasploit-framework-db-4.11.0.pre.dev.gem
An error occurred while installing metasploit-framework-db (4.11.0.pre.dev), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install metasploit-framework-db -v '4.11.0.pre.dev'
succeeds before bundling.`

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497981/installing-metasploit-framework-on-os-x-yosemite-metasploit-framework-v-4-10) exists, but cloning did not work for me. Running mfsupdate reads:

`Using metasploit-framework-db 4.11.0.pre.dev from source at .`

Tried to ran rvssudo bundle install --> ./msfconsole --> 
`Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /opt/msf/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666.[*] Starting the Metasploit Framework console...[*] The initial module cache will be built in the background, this can take 2-5 minutes... /opt/msf/modules/payloads/singles/java/shell_reverse_tcp.rb:54:in initialize': No such file or directory - /opt/msf/data/java/metasploit/Payload.class (Errno::ENOENT)`

Worried my AV Software might have caused some problems. Does anyone who has successfully installed the Metasploit Framework on OS X or Maverick have any ideas?

rvmsudo worked on mfsconsole, but this time the error reads: `/opt/msf/modules/payloads/singles/java/shell_reverse_tcp.rb:54:in initialize: No such file or directory - /opt/msf/data/java/metasploit/Payload.class –  aietsg Dec 31 '14 at 10:34`
See below for more info

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though that Gem needs more access than whatever context you are attempting the bundle install from. If you are using RVM like the blog post shows then you should try using "rvmsudo bundle install"

Comment: thanks for the response. ran rvssudo bundle install --> ./msfconsole `Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /opt/msf/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666.[*] Starting the Metasploit Framework console...[*] The initial module cache will be built in the background, this can take 2-5 minutes...
/opt/msf/modules/payloads/singles/java/shell_reverse_tcp.rb:54:in initialize': No such file or directory - /opt/msf/data/java/metasploit/Payload.class (Errno::ENOENT)`

Comment: Ok, so we are past the bundle install at least. Try rvmsudo on msfconsole as well. I don't know why that guide puts everything in opt and installs it as root but whatever. rvmsudo should work on msfconsole as well as all the other msf tools

Comment: rvmsudo worked on mfsconsole, but this time the error reads: `/opt/msf/modules/payloads/singles/java/shell_reverse_tcp.rb:54:in initialize: No such file or directory - /opt/msf/data/java/metasploit/Payload.class`

Comment: Full Error: `Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /opt/msf/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
[*] Starting the Metasploit Framework console...|[*] The initial module cache will be built in the background, this can take 2-5 minutes...
/opt/msf/modules/payloads/singles/java/shell_reverse_tcp.rb:54:in initialize: No such file or directory - /opt/msf/data/java/metasploit/Payload.class (Errno::ENOENT)`